# Anyone using bgga (or other) closures working in their Android project?

Tags: android, closures, bgga

I miss the closure pattern - anyone have a running example of them on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not heard about anyone using the bgga for Android, but I'm using Scala with sbt-android-plugin (https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin). That works very well and gives you closures and a lot of other niftyness.

Comment: Nice suggestion and interesting. Can't use it on my current app though.